# How to point Amazon S3 bucket to test subdomain like images.develop.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3, subdomain

Currently I'm using Amazon S3 bucket for my website like `images.example.com` .Today I also built a test subdomain for development purposes and it is served in `develop.example.com`

Now I want to use Amazon S3 bucket like `develop.images.example.com` or `images.develop.example.com` (I don't know which of them is correct)

Is it possible according to S3 restrictions?

Because Amazon says: **You must have same bucket name with your subdomain.** So I was create a bucket like `images.example.com`

and my cname record is: `images.example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com`

My webserver is Apache and runs on Ubuntu

How can reach to my images on my development subdomain?

---

Should I create a new cname record?

Should I do something on my virtual host file?

or what?

Answer (score 1):

To share static content from `develop.images.example.com`:

- Create an Amazon S3 bucket called `develop.images.example.com`
- Turn on static website hosting
- Create a Route 53 `A` record for `develop.images.example.com` with `Alias=YES` and point it to your S3 bucket

This is the same process as you would have followed for `images.example.com`.